# Grab data attribute from an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a jQuery event which is part of a backbone class that I am trying to grab the data-attribute from called 'data-foreground'

My function looks as follows..

```
foreground: function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "") {
        this.findClickedElement(e, "li");
        return false;
    }

    console.log(e.target.id); // this returns the id which is '115'
    ... more code
}
```

How can I grab the data-attribute on the li as follows:

```
<li class="item" id="115" data-foreground="blue" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. in vanillaJS using `getAttribute()`

```
e.target.getAttribute('data-foreground');
```

or with `dataset`, (accessing without `data-` prefix) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset))

```
e.target.dataset.foreground
```